# Windows TableLayoutPanel not showing controls

Tags: c++-cli

Am I missing anything that would prevent the child controls from appearing in the panel. Right now, none of the controls are showing, just a blank panel. I just new a hint on what I am missing in the initialization.

```
pane = gcnew TableLayoutPanel ();
pane->Anchor = AnchorStyles::Left | AnchorStyles::Right | AnchorStyles::Top | AnchorStyles::Bottom;
//pane->RowCount = ;
pane->Size = Size;
pane->ColumnCount = 1;
pane->BackColor = Color::AliceBlue;
// Add progess bars
AddProgressBars ();  
Controls->Add (pane);
```

Some of the code for the AddProgressBars function.

```
    int statusBarCount = 10;        // the number of progress bars
    progressBars = gcnew ArrayList (statusBarCount);

    int y = 2;  // the y coord for the progress bar
    for each 
        (System::Windows::Forms::ProgressBar ^pb in progressBars)
    {
        pb->Size = System::Drawing::Size (200, 15);
        pb->Location = Point (2, y);
        pb->Dock = DockStyle::Bottom;
        pane->Controls->Add (pb);
        y += 10;
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried using SetColumn()/SetRow() on the controls after adding them?

Comment: I think I know it is now. See if you guys can figure it out. This really got me.